# Forwarding URL from Webservice

Tags: web-services

We have system architecture as so:

WebApplication --> MediatorService ---> Service Provider --> Device

WebApplication --> which process input and inserts into database.

MediatorService --> is a WebService Application which is running on  the same server where WebApplication is running or on the different server

Service Provider  --> SMS Service Provider which route the messages send from the Mediator Service Application.

Device   --> Which receive the Message from the Service Provider and acts relevant to that message.

Technologies using:

Java/J2EE, Apache Tomcat Server, Struts2.0 framework

Issues :

1. How can I send the message from MediatorService Application Service Provider

   I used response.SendRedirect("Service Provider URL"), but strange it's not 
   working, even though if it works its not the right solution because in out scenarios URL should not change .

   i.e. sending SMS message to the Service Provider should be Back end processing
2. And if I use response.SendRedirect("Service Provider URL") I cannot the response returned by Service Provider.
3. Should use Requestdispatcher.Forward(request,response) or any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong...  It sounds like your Web app is making a web service call to your mediator, and then the mediator has to forward the request to the service provider somehow.  Normally a web-service call is an HTTP POST with an XML body, so I don't think doing a SendRedirect/Forward with the web app will be able to forward the request to the service provider.

Does your service provider expose a web service interface?  If it does, your mediator should probably just make another web service call to the provider, and then the provider can respond back to the mediator with a normal HTTP response, which can then respond back to the web app.